# Is retry-using STM action guaranteed interruptible in GHC / Haskell?

Tags: haskell, concurrency, stm

In https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.1.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#interruptible, we have the guarantee that

> STM transactions that do not use retry [..] are guaranteed not to be interruptible

But what about the converse - I have an `STM` operation using `retry` that I desire to be interruptible (at least when it encounters the retry).

So, strictly reading the guarantee, it is allowed for GHC to keep that retry-using STM action non-interruptible. But does it?

(Edited: I mis-attributed some non-delivery of an interrupt due to the retry-ing STM action not getting interrupted, when in fact I had an earlier leaky interruption point that got interrupted. So in the end, the retry-ing (and orElse-less, see comment from @Taren) STM action was interruptible as expected).

Comment: Actually closing.. I had a problem at some other point (there were other interruptible points which leaked the exception before it could get to the STM action). So likely retry-ing STM will indeed be interruptible (at least no evidence it isn').

Comment: Retry walks up the stack. If it hits an orElse alternative, it doesn't block. If it hits the atomically frame it waits until a variable in the readset updates, which is interruptible. https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/2b1faea90dff1ad743925eb5a0b552a11c514349/rts/PrimOps.cmm#L1491